# Can I use an Ubuntu bootable USB on a MacBook Air M1?

Tags: live-usb, macbook

I seem to be not able to boot my MacBook Air from a bootable USB with Ubuntu installed. I had found earlier that there was no support on M1 for Linux-based OS.

Is it still true or has someone found a sort of solution?

Comment: There is currently no functional version of Ubuntu for devices with Apple’s M-series chips. The closest you’ll get is [Asahi Linux](https://asahilinux.org/), but be ready for the compatibility caveats that come with installing a non-Apple OS on Apple hardware.

Comment: @matigo, please don't answer in comments.

Comment: The Asahi developers have reverse engineered the M1 GPU recently. https://asahilinux.org/2022/11/tales-of-the-m1-gpu/ Also, Asahi is very easy to install or uninstall. https://asahilinux.org/2022/03/asahi-linux-alpha-release/

Comment: [Multipass](https://multipass.run/) and other VM solutions work very well upon M1 hardware.

Comment: @user535733 I need to start Macbook from bootable USB. Why do I need a virtual machine?

Comment: If you want to ask about any Linux distro running on Apple M1, you should rather ask on [unix.se].

Comment: It does now, I have Fedora running on the M1 pro. And here you can manage to boot a Live:
https://www.corellium.com/blog/linux-m1

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no official images for the Apple M1 line of hardware.

The supported hardware platforms are listed in the official documentation - unfortunately, this is not updated for 22.04 and 22.10 yet. But [here is the list](https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/installation-guide/index.html) for 20.04.

This is further evident from the [CD Image site](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04.1/release/), which lists the same available images.

If there was an image for Apple M1, you would surely know about this on the [Ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/) website, and the image would also be available for download from here.

Until this happens, Apple M1 (and M2) hardware is officially not supported.